# CartoDB edit markers

Tags: carto, markers

I'm using cartodb.js in my HTML file. I have this code:

```
var layerSource = {
            user_name: 'myuser',
            type: 'cartodb',
             sublayers: [{
             sql: "SELECT * FROM post",
               cartocss: '#post {marker-fill: red;}'
                        }] 
                   }
```

Does someone know how I could get each single markers to be draggable and editable?

Now I am sure the Google Maps API can display my base map but with this library, I can't select the markers in the CartoDB Layer.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you're receiving an image (tile) that is showing your points, but the points are not individual elements in this rendered map (you can move them in the CartoDB Editor).

There's not an out of the box CartoDB solution for this, but some resources that can be useful:

- [Read AND write to CartoDB with the Leaflet.draw plugin](http://blog.cartodb.com/read-and-write-to-cartodb-with-the-leaflet-draw-plugin/)
- [Getting the geometry with the SQL API to use it with Leaflet](http://bl.ocks.org/javisantana/8313604)

You could try to play with the second approach as you'll have the geometries available directly in the client side by getting them with the API.